# Не обновляется отправляемое фото в aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, google-spreadsheet, диаграммы

При публикации диаграммы в google таблицах в виде картинки получаю вот такую ссылку

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQDJtYrVuho_jeNjB5MhBYovu50UjSmoRAhzus6ybaoqeXL4_bQckPsqhrCl7sk-tiJDRCu7AU445Lp/pubchart?oid=1591529677&format=image
```

далее пытаюсь отправить ее в телеграм-боте (aiogram)

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="photo")
async def cmd_photo(message: types.Message):
    url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQDJtYrVuho_jeNjB5MhBYovu50UjSmoRAhzus6ybaoqeXL4_bQckPsqhrCl7sk-tiJDRCu7AU445Lp/pubchart?oid=1591529677&format=image'
    await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo=url)
```

картинка успешно отправляется, но при последующих запросах бот присылает не обновленную картинку, а ту, которую прислал в самый первый раз, как будто он при первой отправке ее кэширует и далее выдает из кэша, хотя данные в диаграмме меняются каждый час. Если эту ссылку вставить в браузер, то открывается обновленная картинка диаграммы. Можно как то это побороть?

Comment: А если перезапустить бот?

Comment: @oleksandrigo, нет, картинка не обновляется

Comment: Значит проблема не в боте, а в гугле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя время решил вернуться к своей проблеме и нашел решение. Для отправки картинки по ссылке, а не из файла нужно использовать `URLInputFile`

таким образом решением будет таким:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="photo")
async def cmd_photo(message: types.Message):
    url = URLInputFile('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQDJtYrVuho_jeNjB5MhBYovu50UjSmoRAhzus6ybaoqeXL4_bQckPsqhrCl7sk-tiJDRCu7AU445Lp/pubchart?oid=1591529677&format=image')
    await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo=url)
```

возможно кто-то столкнется с аналогичной задачей и будет искать решение